# Parceler - Unable to find generated Parcelable class

Tags: android, parceler

**EDIT**

After clean and rebuilt, classes are not generated

---

I got this error while trying to use `Parcels.wrap()`

```
Unable to find generated Parcelable class for xyz.xyz.models.reclamation.Reclamation, verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class xyz.xyz.models.reclamation.Reclamation$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.
```

But `Reclamation$$Parcelable` class is created and I can see its content.

Thats my gradle:

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
```

Trying to change `annotationProcessor` to `apt` causes build error.

Thats Reclamation class

```
@Parcel
public class Reclamation {

public Reclamation() {
}

private int reclamationProductID;

private Integer preference;

private String takingDate1;

private String takingDate2;

private int takingAddressID;

private String takingAddressStreet;

private String takingAddressCity;

private String takingAddressZipCode;

private int type;

private String takingAddressCompany;
// + getters setters
}
```

Thats the line where it crashes

```
ServiceStepFour_.builder().arg(Constants.ARG_RECLAMATION, Parcels.wrap(reclamation)).build();
```

I use it in combination with Android Annotations.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Any chance you have proguard configured in your build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although documentation says you have to put these lines to the gradle:

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
```

change it to:

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
```

Make sure all files you want to use are annotated with `@Parcel`.

I have class A with class B variable and I forgot to annotate class B. That's why changing from `annotationProcessor` to `apt` gaves me an build error.

Comment: @JohnEricksen glad to meet you :) yes, I am using apt instead of annotationProcessor

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late answer but maybe someone else has this issue later,

If you are using `Kotlin` in your code you must use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` to solve the issue

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have to **remove** this line when I move from apt to annotationProcessor

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```